# Deleting branches on Azure DevOps with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-repos

I am trying to delete old branches which are x days old from Azure DevOps by using Powershell, but it is unsuccessful. Could you please help me out on this matter or if you have any better idea to execute this task, I am more than welcome to hear them out! I have been stuck with it for a few weeks now.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you give more detail of what you try exactly that doesn't work?

Comment: Just run `git` commands in powershell?

Comment: @YLR, so I am trying to use a powershell script to delete (remotely) branches present on Azure DevOps Repo but it turns out to be unsuccessful

Comment: @RoadRunner Yes, I am trying the following script:

git checkout master; git branch -D  @(git branch | select-string -Match "NAME" | Foreach {$_.Line.Trim()})

But it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

> Deleting branches on Azure DevOps with Powershell

You could use the REST API to delete those Branch.

However, we do not recommend you to do this. It is not safe to use scripts to delete some old branches, because the script cannot determine whether the branch is important, but it is risky to delete based on the date. So you need to be clear about this before deleting.

First, we could use the REST API [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to list all the branches for the Repo:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=6.0
```

Then, we loop each branch with REST API [Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?&searchCriteria.compareVersion.version=<YouBranchName>&api-version=6.0
```

And compare creation date or activation date, use the REST API to delete those branches:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization name}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=5.1
```

Request Body:

```
[  
  {     
    "name": "{branchName}",     
    "oldObjectId": "{branchObjectId}",     
    "newObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"       
  } 
]
```

Alternatively, if you want use git command line to delete, you could refer below document for some more details:

[Deleting Old Local Branches With PowerShell](https://dalehirt.com/2017/11/20/git-tip-deleting-old-local-branches-with-powershell/comment-page-1/)

Comment: Thanks @Leo , I will implement the aforementioned steps in my task and will let you know of the outcome.

Comment: @TejeshRamrukheea, How about the result? Have you time to try to this？